# Android PagedList Scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I'm using Android Jetpack Paging library(2.1.2) for a chat view.
Data is served from a local database(room) and network by using PagedList.BoundaryCallback mechanism. Since the Room provide paged data to the RecyclerView adapter I'm unable to scroll to the bottom of list as the list size is unknown.

I also registerd **registerAdapterDataObserver** for adapter to observe the changes. However
itemCount value in **onItemRangeInserted** callback changed from time to time.

So how do you guys scroll to bottom of the RecyclerView when you are using PagedListAdapter with BoundaryCallback ?

Comment: Do you have placeholders enabled? BoundaryCallback works by invalidating DataSource and reloading items around current scroll position to pickup the new items, so adapter.itemCount isn't necessarily a strictly increasing number

Comment: Didn't enable placeholders because, the cell heights may vary with each other. Can't find a way to scroll to the bottom of list when chat starts

Comment: Have you looked into setting `PagingConfig.initialKey`? That sounds closer to what you want rather than loading the entire chat history then scrolling to the bottom? Otherwise `adapter.itemCount` gives you the total number of items being presented in the list and you want to listen on `loadStateFlow` to scroll to `adapter.itemCount - 1` after refresh finishes.

Comment: I was unable to find PagingConfig.initialKey in version 2.0. It may be associated with version 3.0. I'm unable to update the project to Paging 3.0 as it may have a lot of work to migrate and it is still under alpha channel.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - I replied without reading carefully enough. In paging2, the concept is still the same, but since load state isn't a concept that's built-in, you'll need some way to wait for adapter to be notified of all the items before checking `adapter.itemCount`.

Comment: The question is wrong, because in every context where you have paged results, the "scroll to bottom" is not a primary goal of paging of 999999999999999999999999 items... Consider instead to revert the order to have the last item at the top.

Answer (score 0):

For this we need to extend the positional datasource, and override loadInitial() method. Basically room uses the limit and offset in sqlite to load specific range of data from the specific position. Codes are in Kotlin but can be easily understandable and convertable in Java

```
override fun loadInitial(
    params: LoadInitialParams,
    callback: LoadInitialCallback<ChatListItem>
) {
    val newRequestedSize = params.requestedStartPosition + params.requestedLoadSize
    val dbMessage = groupMessagesDao.getPagedMessageForGroup(
        channelId,
        0,
        newRequestedSize
    )
    if (dbMessage.isNotEmpty()) {
        callback.onResult(dbMessage, 0)
    } else {
        callback.onResult(emptyList(), params.requestedStartPosition)
    }
}
```

In the above code we are forcing the room(you will have to implement your own Dao of course, it just uses the offset and limit as I mentioned earlier) to load the initial data from position 0 to the newRequestedSize which is the sum of current offset and load size the paging library wants us to load. Once, we load the data from position 0 to the current page position, we need to set the callback with the data and the position which is 0. Now, the paging library loads the data up to the current page position and our

```
private fun scrollToBottom() {
        val position = adapter.itemCount - 1
        if (position > 0) {
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
        }
    }
```

function works as expected.
One thing we also need to handle is to listen for table change, which you can again find in the LimitOffsetDatasource on how the room does it.

```
init {
    val tableObserver = object : InvalidationTracker.Observer(tableName) {
        override fun onInvalidated(tables: MutableSet<String>) {
            // invalidate the dataSource
            Log.v("dataSource invalidate requested!")
            invalidate()
        }
    }
    database.invalidationTracker.addObserver(tableObserver)
    addInvalidatedCallback {
        Log.v("invalidation callback received, removing table observer")
        database.invalidationTracker.removeObserver(tableObserver)
    }
}
```

The performance implication are there in this approach, but in our case the user is most of the time messaging which is always at the first page. So, when the user is at bottom this implementation is same as that of the LimitOffsetDatasource. Only when the user scrolls to see the old messages, and at the same time a new message arrives for the user only then we reload all the messages up to the user current position. But when new message arrives most probably the user will scroll to bottom. So, the performance penalty is virtually zero.